# URL routing not working with ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, url-routing, iis-express

I've recently started a web application and decided to use url routing in it (basically just to get some practice with it).

The app is .NET4, and I'm using VS2010 SP1 and IIS Express (integrated pipeline).

The thing is, when I run the app, routing works fine as long as there's no parameter in the route URL. If there is a parameter, then I get a 404.

Here's the relevant code from global.asax.cs:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Clear();
    routes.MapPageRoute("Users_Edit", "users/view/{username}", "~/users/user_detail.aspx", false);
    routes.MapPageRoute("Users_Create", "users/create", "~/users/user-detail.aspx", false);    
}

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

The app is running on IIS Express from VS. The virtual folder is /cms.

If I go to `http://localhost:8888/cms/users/create` I see my page as intended.

If I go to `http://localhost:8888/cms/users/view/Matt` I get a 404 error (from ASP.NET not from IIS, so the request is going into the ASP.NET pipeline).

I've tried adding the following to web.config, but this didn't make any difference:

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I've tried changing to Classic mode in IIS Express but that made no difference. Neither did using good old Cassini rather than IIS Express.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a typo the actual page name in the non-working route. You have used `page_detail.aspx` in this route while in working route, you have used `page-detail.aspx` - notice the underscore vs hyphen. So I believe fixing that should do the trick i.e.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Users_Edit", "users/view/{username}", "~/users/user-detail.aspx", false);
```

Comment: OMG (slaps forehead). I spent all afternoon tearing my hair out with this yesterday and it was just a typo staring me in the face! I need a holiday! Thank you very much!